# Read, Process and save bson file

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pdf, bson

I have a .bson file.
Inside the .bson file, I have a PDF whose data type is bytes.
I need to burn the PDF. which is inside the .bson file in a readable format. Does PDF make sense?

I need help, the steps I have to do in between
Note: I already saved the content in a PDF file and it says the file is damaged
My code:

```py
    with open ('LOL.bson') as myfile:
        content = myfile.read()
        print(content)

    {"_id":{"$oid":"59d3522618206812388e35f1"},"files_id":{"$oid":"59d3522618206812388e35f0"},"n":0,"data":{"$binary":"JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFuZyhwdC1QVCkgL1N0cnVjdFRyZWVSb290IDUzIDAgUi9NYXJrSW5mbzw8L01hcmtlZCB0cnVlPj4+Pg0KZW5kb2JqDQoyIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL1BhZ2VzL0NvdW50IDEvS2lkc1sgMyAwIFJdID4+DQplbmRvYmoNCjMgMCBvYmoNCjw8L1R5cGUvUGFnZS9QYXJlbnQgMiAwIFIvUmVzb3VyY2VzPDwvRXh0R1N0YXRlPDwvR1M1IDUgMCBSL0dTOCA4IDA....
```

Type of data

```py
read_content = bson.json_util.loads(content)
print(read_content['data']) 
b'%PDF-1.5\r\n%\xb5\xb5\xb5\xb5\r\n1 0 obj\r\n<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0 R/Lang(pt-PT) /StructTreeRoot 130 0 R/MarkInfo<</Marked true>>>>\r\nendobj\r\n2 0 obj\r\n<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[ 3 0 R] >>\r\nendobj\r\n3 0 obj\r\n<</Type/Page/Parent 2 0 R/Resources<</ExtGState<</GS5 5 0 R/GS8 8 0 R>>/Font<</F1 6 0 R/F2 29 0 R>>/XObject<</Image9 9 0 R/Image11 11 0 R/Image13 13 0 R/Image15 15 0 R/Image17 17 0 R/Image19 19 0 R/Image21 21 0 R/Image23 23 0 R/Image25 25 0 R/Image27 27 0 R/Image32 32 0 R/Image34 34 0 R/Image35 35 0 R/Image37 37 0 R/Image39 39 0 R/Image41 41 0 R/Image43 43 0 R/Image45 45 0 R/Image47 47 0 R/Image49 49 0 R/Image51 51 0 R/Image53 53 0 R/Image55 55 0 R/Image57 57 0 R/Image59 59 0 R/Image61 61 0 R/Image63 63 0 R/Image65 65 0 R/Image67 67 0 R/Image69 69 0 R/Image71 71 0 R/Image73 73 0 R/Image75 75 0 R/Image77 77 0 R/Image79 79 0 R/Image81 81 0 R/Image83 83 0 R/Image85 85 0 R/Image87 87 0 R/Image89 89 0 R/Image91 91 0 R/Image93 93 0 R/Image95 95 0 R/Image97 97 0 R/Image99 99 0 R/Image101 101 0 R/Image103 103 0 R/Image105 105 0 R/Image107 107 0 R/Image109 109 0 R/Image111 111 0 R/Image113 113 0 R/Image115 115 0 R/Image117 117 0 R/Image119 119 0 R/Image121 121 0 R/Image123 123 0 R/Image125 125 0 R/Image127 127 0 R>>/Pattern<</P31 31 0 R/P33 33 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageB/ImageC/ImageI] >>/MediaBox[ 0 0 960 540] /Contents 4 0 R/Group<</Type/Group/S/Transparency/CS/DeviceRGB>>/Tabs/S/StructParents 0>>\r\nendobj\r\n4 0 obj\r\n<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 4008>>\r\nstream\r\nx\x9c\xbd[\xcb\x8e\x1d\xb7\x11\xdd\x0f0\xff\xd0K\xc9\x80Z|?\x00\xc3\x0b?"\xd8\x88\x11\'V\x90\x85\xe1\x850\x91\x15\x07\x1a\t\x91\x8c
read_content = bson.json_util.loads(content)
print(type(read_content['data']))
   
> `<class 'bytes'>
```

How to save .bson content in a readable format (PDF).

Comment: Have you tried the obvious `open('xxx.pdf','wb').write(read_content['data'])`?

Comment: yes. I get the message: "The Pdf is damaged"

Comment: I just want to double-check that you opened the file as mode `'wb'`, and didn't try to `decode` it into Unicode.  That wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes... BBut I can't open the pdf.. I get a message saying it's damaged.
However when I open that pdf inside python. I can open it, but I don't get much value from the information, because it's in bytes.

Comment: There isn't much we can do without seeing the whole data.  Certainly the start of your string is the start of a PDF file.  Perhaps you should post the whole JSON somewhere.

Comment: @Tim Roberts Can you share, your email or other contact?

Comment: It would be friendlier for you to put it on some snippet-sharing service, but you can email to timr at probo dot com.

Comment: @Tim Roberts I didn't realize what the email was.

Comment: Is your `.bson` file really `BSON`?  When I `bson.encode({"data": pdf_bytes})`, the result is a python binary string.

Comment: @KJ quando eu guardo o bson em pdf. ele apresenta a seguinte mensagem: Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open 't...pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, ir was sent as an email attachment and asn't correctly decoded).
can you give me your email to explain in detail on skype?

Comment: @KJ I saved the PDF file in bytes:
fp = open("Test2.pdf", "wb")
fp.write(read_content['data'])
fp.close()

Comment: Thanks. I need to extract the text and images.

Comment: The real problem is that I was never able to open the pdf locally. It always opens with a message saying that it has not been decoded properly or is damaged. :(

Comment: No :(
I have a .bson file extracted from BD Mongo. Through python I saw that inside the .bson file I have a pdf file.
I want to save this .pdf file in a readable format. Because it's embedded inside the .bson.
I've already tried to save this .pdf through python functions, but I get a message saying it's damaged or decoded :( And I need to analyze the content of this pdf, in a human-readable format. Because it's in pdf format, but nothing is understood, because it is in bytes.

Comment: So, do I have to first save the pdf as a valid binary file for conversion? And what would the format be?

And then open that file in python and convert it to pdf. That's it?

Comment: This task, not appear more easy ;/